# Regex I need to find if the number between 0 and 60

Tags: java, selenium

I have a string

```
cheaprate = Discount $40!
```

I need to verify if the cost is between 0 and 60. If its between 0 and 60 its a pass!

```
public void cost() {

    String regex = "(.)*(\\d)(.)*";   

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

    String href = cheaprate.getAttribute("text"); ==// Discount $40!
    Matcher m = p.matcher(href);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(" Cost 0 - 60.00");
    } else        
        throw new Exception("Fail");

}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: String = ($579.00/pass). How would you extract a number 579.00. I'm lost how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
.*\$([0-5]?\d|60)!
```

Comment: Thanks! What about ($200.00/pass) how would you extract a number.